# Google Sheets API with Python, border check

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets-api

Is there any way to check that is current cell in sheet has a bold border? I want to use this to separate areas

I only found how to change it, not to check. thats not cool

Comment: What is `current cell` you expect?

Comment: I mean I'd want to chek that some cell (for example A2) has a bold border and get True or False

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I'd want to chek that some cell (for example A2) has a bold border and get True or False`, a cell has 4 sides. In this case, if you want to check cell "A2", which side do you want to check? And, in your tags, `python` and `google-apps-script` are used. Which language do you want to use? And, can you provide your current script? I apologize that I  am trying to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Oh, im sorry for adding Apps Script, it was wrong, i using Python.  In my case i need to check a bottom border

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, how about updating your question? In that case, can you add your current script?

Comment: i deleted wrong tag. At this moment i don't have any code for this. I trying searching for any methods to solve my problem. I only have a code that can copy certain (in code) areas from Google Sheet and send it to Telegram bot